# Switch pro controller disconnects and reconnects bluetooth. 19.04

Tags: bluetooth

Using the controller with steam and it constantly is disconnecting and reconnecting. Sometimes it takes a few minutes and sometimes its almost instant. Tried un-pairing and re-pairing it. I don't have any other bluetooth devices to see if it's just the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late reply, but just found out the answer.
You'll need to disable Ubuntu's Enhanced Re-Transmission Mode, which conflicts with how the controller works.
In order to do that, you'll need to add:

```
options bluetooth disable_ertm=1
```

to `/etc/modprobe.d/bluetooth.conf` and restart your PC.